# The simplest way to present a Lie algebra to a wide audience?

Tags: terminology, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I would like to get suggestions from you as to the best way to present the idea and contents of Lie algebras to a wide public of people with no detailed background in maths. What wlould you explain to them? Which kinds of images or metaphors would you use for illustration and so on?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: On the face of it, "Lie algebras" and "popular lecture" seem an odd combination, since Lie algebras are technical and fairly arcane. What kind of background (age, education, exposure to mathematics...) can you assume? Why Lie algebras in particular? What do you want the audience to take away from the lecture?

Comment: And why did you choose this particular topic, as opposed to something less complicated, say, in linear algebra? I suppose you might do something like the application of Lie algebras to parallel parking, but even this requires some calculus ...

Comment: Lie algebras and a wide public of people seems indeed not to be the best idea. I could only imagine some geometry, like isometries of $3$-dimensional space, rotations, translations, forming a (Lie) group; passing to linear algebra, then a Lie algebra.

Comment: Well, I am trying to present to an audience of high school students (age 17-18) some of the properties of algebra (also of Lie algebrae) which can account for the way human language works (in the sense its elements group with each other and so on, not so much in the sense of conveying a functional meaning about the external world).